# spark cannot create LabeledPoint

Tags: python, apache-spark

I always get this error:
AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'substring(l,1,-1)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (string or binary) type, however, 'l' is of array type.;"

Quite confused because l[0] is a string, and matches arg 1.
dataframe has only one column named 'value', which is a comma separated string.
And I want to convert this original dataframe to another dataframe of object LabeledPoint, with the first element to be 'label' and the others to be 'features'.

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

def parse_points(dataframe):

    df1=df.select(split(dataframe.value,',').alias('l'))
    u_label_point=udf(LabeledPoint)
    df2=df1.select(u_label_point(col('l')[0],col('l')[1:-1]))
    return df2

parsed_points_df = parse_points(raw_data_df)
```

Comment: You should improve your question I can't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you what to create LabeledPoint in dataframe. So you can:

def parse_points(df):

```
df1=df.select(split(df.value,',').alias('l'))   
df2=df1.map(lambda seq: LabeledPoint(float(seq[0][0]),seq[0][1:])) # since map applies lambda in each tuple
return df2.toDF() #this will convert pipelinedRDD to dataframe
```

parsed_points_df = parse_points(raw_data_df)

Comment: Thanks. This method perfectly work. However I still do not understand why using udf will give an error?